# How do I call “@” at-symbol quotation in C?

Tags: c, language-features

Having seen Fossil's code [ https://fossil-scm.org/home/annotate?filename=src/schema.c&checkin=b03652382a327740  L27.. ]:

```c
    /*
    ** The database schema for the ~/.fossil configuration database.
    */
    const char zConfigSchema[] =
    @ -- This file contains the schema for the database that is kept in the
    @ -- ~/.fossil file and that stores information about the users setup.
    @ --
    @ CREATE TABLE global_config(
    @   name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    @   value TEXT
    @ );
    @
    @ -- Identifier for this file type.
    @ -- The integer is the same as 'FSLG'.
    @ PRAGMA application_id=252006675;
    ;
```

I'm wondering what is `@...` syntax is for. I have never seen it before, and I do not know how to call it to search the web for it. "string literal extensions in C" and various rephrasing of that yield no result.

*Please consider leaving this question be, despite its triviality, for the purpose of better discoverability. Thanks.*

Comment: It looks like a marker that is used by a pre-processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "BUILD.txt" of the project:

> - Most *.c source files are preprocessed using a program called
>     "translate".  The sources to translate are found in src/translate.c.
>     A header comment in src/translate.c explains in detail what it does.

More information can be found directly in the [referenced file](https://fossil-scm.org/home/artifact/331bea4cfc50a1cf), but it seems to be used to better handle CGI capabilities in C, particularly in generating HTML.

The synopsis provided in that "src/translate.c" is as follows:

> ** Input lines that begin with the "@" character are translated into
>   ** either cgi_printf() statements or string literals and the
>   ** translated code is written on standard output.
>   **
>   ** The problem this program is attempt to solve is as follows:  When
>   ** writing CGI programs in C, we typically want to output a lot of HTML
>   ** text to standard output.  In pure C code, this involves doing a
>   ** printf() with a big string containing all that text.  But we have
>   ** to insert special codes (ex: \n and \") for many common characters,
>   ** which interferes with the readability of the HTML.
>   **
>   ** This tool allows us to put raw HTML, without the special codes, in
>   ** the middle of a C program.  This program then translates the text
>   ** into standard C by inserting all necessary backslashes and other
>   ** punctuation.